# Moving object in AS3 while it is translated by Matrix3D

Tags: actionscript-3

First, please look at my SWF: http://krakow45.pl/spec/warcaby/Warcaby3D.html

You can move pawns and it works pretty well. But the problem starts whem you translate game board (by pressing any of direction keys). After this you cant move pawns. Here is little piece of my code:

translation:

```
case Keyboard.LEFT:
    _matrix = new Matrix3D();

_matrix.appendTranslation(0, -200, 0);
_matrix.appendRotation(_rot++, Vector3D.X_AXIS);
_matrix.appendTranslation(0, 200, _depth);

_table._board.transform.matrix3D = _matrix;

break;
```

moving the pawn:

```
private function MouseDown(event:MouseEvent):void
    {
        var pawn:Pawn = event.currentTarget as Pawn;

        _xPos = pawn._xPos;
        _yPos = pawn._yPos;

        _txt.text = pawn._xPos + " - " + pawn._yPos + "\n";

        pawn.startDrag();
    }
```

Comment: Do you enter your listener when the board is moved?

Comment: I think yes, becouse when I move it and try to move pawn, textfield which is next to board returns position

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I solved this by using something like this: (against startStag() )

```
private var _clicked:Boolean
private var _currentPawn:Pawn

private function MouseDown(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    _clicked = true;
    _currentPawn = event.currentTarget as Pawn;
    // rest of my code
}

private function MouseMove(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    if(_clicked)
    {
        _currentPawn.x = mouseX;
        _currentPawn.y = mouseY;
    }
}

private function MouseUp(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    _clicked = false;
// rest of my code
}
```